# How to use STLSoft library on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I was following the installation step on this post: http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/stlsoft-installation/

I set it up as follows (because I don't have a D-drive):

1. Extract the file to C:\
2. Right click project -> properties -> Debug -> Environment: `PATH=%PATH%;C:\stlsoft-1.9.117;`
3. properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories: `C:\stlsoft-1.9.117\include`

However, when I run the sample code in the post, it outputs:
`error LNK1561: entry point must be defined`

Might anyone know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application needs a `main` function as its entry point and the sample in the blog post is incomplete. Try this:

```
#include <stlsoft/conversion/integer_to_string.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string int2string(int i)    
{
    char buf[30];    // 29 digits, enough for longest integer, even 64-bit
    const char* s = stlsoft::integer_to_string(buf, i);
    return std::string(s);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]{
    std::cout << int2string(5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much!! I'll mark your answer once stackoverflow lets me.